# file_get_contents inside the controller not working in prestashop

Tags: php, controller, prestashop, file-get-contents, prestashop-1.6

I was trying to access a file content inside the controller.

```
 $data= file_get_contents($this->module->getPath()."data/file.json");
 print_r(var_dump($data));
```

var_dump output gives boolean(false). How to access the content's of the file?

Comment: Check `var_dump($this->module->getPath()."data/file.json")` and make sure the file exists and is readable by the PHP / webserver user.

Comment: The file is there, I can access it from the browser with the same path when  I print using    
 
print($this->module->getPath()."data/file.json")

Comment: What is the value it gives you? If you can access it from browser using the value it gives you, it seems unlikely it's going to be the same path on the server's file system. Either way `file_get_contents` will only return false when there is an error.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to mention that your path is wrong.

```
print_r($this>->module->getPath() . "data/file.json");
```

This will output: `yourModuleName/data/file.json`

But your controller lies in `controller/admin/`

So it will search the file in `controller/admin/yourModuleName/data/file.json`

Maybe try this (not tested):

```
"/../../".$this>->module->getPath()."data/file.json"
```